# Mysql traverse relationship across multiple tables without doing joins

Tags: mysql, database

I have multiple tables in Mysql.
Let's call them A,B,C,D. all of them are linked to each other as chain. for example
There would be entries in the table such that
A.id = B.a_id
B.id = C.b_id
C.id = D.c_id.

I have A's id with me. I want to query all the rows from A,B,C,D which are linked with A's id.

Here are some ways I can think of

1. Make multiple queries from application.
2. do a join of all the tables, and then query by A.id

both of these approaches have tradeoffs

In the first approach

1. multiple round trips would be involved,
2. by the time I do subsequent fetch, some record might have changed.

In the second approach

1. join across multiple large table may not be feasible at large scale (correct me if i am wrong here, would mysql try to join only certain rows? but not whole table? if that is the case, join might even work in my case. But i am not aware of other downsides)

Below are the questions i have

1. Is it possible to do this in mysql or should I use graph datastores?
2. even if mysql optimizes fetching only relevant rows. since in join same row would be repeated lots of times, it would result in quite a lot of data transfer. Is it possible to optimise it? i.e. only fetch rows from table but not joined rows.